# lucene search is working for only small letters

Tags: lucene

i am adding my lucene document like following

```
final Document document = new Document();
        document.add(new Field("login", user.getLogin(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
        document.add(new Field("email", user.getEmail(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        document.add(new Field("firstName", user.getFirstName(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        document.add(new Field("lastName", user.getLastName(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        userIndexWriter.addDocument(document);
```

So if i search with small letters , the search is successful, but if i search with capital letters, the search returns nothing.

Anybody has a clue if i am missing something..?

```
analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);


                final IndexWriterConfig indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36, analyzer);

                final IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, indexWriterConfig);
```

and my search manager

```
final SearcherManager searcherManager = new SearcherManager(indexWriter, true, null);
```

and i am searching like following

```
final BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();

            final Query query1 = new PrefixQuery(new Term("email", prefix));
            final Query query2 = new PrefixQuery(new Term("firstName", prefix));
            final Query query3 = new PrefixQuery(new Term("lastName", prefix));

            booleanQuery.add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
            booleanQuery.add(query2, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
            booleanQuery.add(query3, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

            final SortField sortField = new SortField("firstName", SortField.STRING, true);
            final Sort sort = new Sort(sortField);

            final TopDocs topDocs = searcherManager .search(booleanQuery, DEFAULT_TOP_N_SEARCH_USER, sort);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you apply the same analysis to both the document and query. For instance, if you set the indexing analyzer to be StandardAnalzyer, then you need also to apply it to your query like this:

```
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "firstName", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT));
    try {
        Query q = queryParser.parse("Ameer");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You need to use QueryParser in order to apply the same analysis. The term query does not apply any analysis. So, small letter will match but the capital will not.

Comment: Thanks. Please add  your comment as answer than i will accept it. I didnt got much time to test but seems the capital issue is resolved.